# Yii2 - Pass table field to view from other controller

Tags: php, database, variables, controller, yii2

I have this DetailView that renders in a view belonging to `ProdutosController` some fields (foto, nome, etc.). Inside the detailView is a hyperlink that displays for every recorded showed and when pressed renders a view from `EncomendasController`, and `EncomendasController` must show only the name *(field nome)* of the product in which i activate the 'Comprar' hyperlink.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options' => ['class' => 'detail1-galeria-view2'],
    'attributes' => [
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
            'attribute'=>'',
            //'value'=>$model->foto,
            'value'=>Html::a(Html::img(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() . "/" .$model->foto, ['width'=>'192', 'height' => "256"]), $model->foto),
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->nome,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->categoria,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->descricao,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->valor.' '.'€',
        ],
        // info
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create'])),
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

**How can i pass only the field "nome" from the product detailView in which i pressed the hyperlink button to another view belonging to the other controller named `EncomendasController` and then show in the new view that same name?**

Comment: You want to pass only name to other controller, and in this controller you want to render one page and echo that name ? Am i right ?

Comment: It's simple Andre. Wait for few minute.

Comment: `Url::to(['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome]);` like this?

Comment: I think not. I need to pass to the other controller: $model->nome, from the ProdutosController and then display it on the new view from other EncomendasController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `controller name` followed by `controller method` as `URL` and pass `'nome'` as attribute. This `'nome'` will be `redirected` to the page.

**View**

```
'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome])),
```

**Controller**

```
class EncomendasController 
{
    .
    .
    public function actionCreate($nome) {

        $nome = Yii::$app->request->get('nome');

        return $this->redirect('create',['nome'=>$nome]);

    }
    .
    .

}
```

**create.php** (view)

```
<?php echo $nome;?>
```

Comment: Ok. But how to pass only the $model->nome and it's value from the record associated to the detailView when user presses the hyperlink .

Comment: ERROR NOT FOUND #404, in http://localhost:8888/beladona/web/index.php?r=encomendas%2Fcreate%3Fnome%3DRamo+Temptation

Comment: have you created create.php page @AndréCastro ?

Comment: Yes i did. Create.php is inside Encomendas folder.

Comment: Ok. Try this `'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create&nome='.$model->nome])),` @AndréCastro

Comment: Another ERROR NOT FOUND #404.

Comment: Show me error like http://localhost:8888/beladona/web/index.php?r=encomendas%2Fcreate%3Fnome%3DRamo+Temptation @AndréCastro

Comment: http://localhost:8888/beladona/web/index.php?r=encomendas%2Fcreate%26nome%3DRamo+Temptation

Comment: I'm fairly new to Yii2, and it's the first time i'm attempting to do this. But how can i solve this issue?

Comment: @Nana you are doing it wrong..refer this..http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: The first example that you gave me worked very well. But now with the $model attached it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this `'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','Comprar'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create', 'nome' => $model->nome])),` @AndréCastro.

Comment: I already did, what you are explaining from last 40 minutes, i have already answered it in my first comment. Please check that.

Comment: It worked @Nana Partykar :) Many thanks to you and also Coderanonymous. Now i know how to do this for the rest of the project.

Comment: @AndréCastro : Glad to hear. Thanks. You are relief. I'm relief. I feel each and every person pain as my pain. Because, i also passed through same pain.